# How to make Lombok + Gson work with Spring AOP proxies

Tags: java, gson, spring-aop, lombok, cglib

Assuming there is a simple class `Student`

```
@Data @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    private String name;
}
```

Add a logging aspect With Spring AOP in aop.xml

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="log" ref="logging">
        <aop:pointcut id="selectAll" expression="execution(* com.tutorial.Student.getName(..))"/>
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="selectAll" method="beforeAdvice"/>
        <aop:after pointcut-ref="selectAll" method="afterAdvice"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
<bean id="student" class="com.tutorial.Student">
    <property name="name"  value="Zara" />
    <property name="age"  value="11"/>
</bean>
```

excluding aspects fields

```
public class ExcludeAspects implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        if(f.getName().startsWith("CGLIB$"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

main,note the output of the first bean is empty ("{}"):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExcludeAspects()).create();
   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("aop.xml");

   //return "{}"
   Student student = (Student) context.getBean("student");
   gson.toJson(student);       

   //works fine
   Student student2 = new Student(11,"Zara");
   gson.toJson(student2);       
}
```

**Update**  According to the accepted answer, `unProxy` works for me.

Comment: I think you should not change your question this much from the original but instead comment the answers. Now Arun's answer seem a bit irrelevant. Does call to `context.getBean("student");` use Gson to deserialize? Have you logged that Student otherwise, what values it has? For debugging you could `name` & `age` to some default debug value.

Comment: values of `name` and `age` of the 2 beans are the same at runtime.

Comment: Not sure if this is anymore AOP thing but may be related to that the `student` bean you get might be a proxy. See also [this queation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5980379/6413377).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to imply that your aspects are working, i.e. before/after advices from your configuration get executed. If they don't, you have problems in other places. I am further assuming that

- your aspects work as designed and you have checked that,
- you are using Spring AOP, not AspectJ with load-time weaving,
- somehow GSON is seeing CGLIB proxies, not the original objects underneath.

Then the problem could be that GSON - I have zero experience with it, never used it before - uses reflection in order to search for fields in the proxy class. But it will not find any as the proxy only overrides methods, but does not have fields because the latter are in the original class (parent to the proxy). If this is true, you need to configure GSON to search in the original class, not in the proxy class. Then you also would not have to exclude anything.

---

**Update:**

My educated guess above was correct.

Just because I was curious about how to get the original object from a CGLIB proxy, I looked at it in a debugger. It seems like every proxy has a public final method `getTargetSource` which you can invoke via reflection:

```java
package com.tutorial;

import org.springframework.aop.TargetSource;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("aop.xml");

    Student student = (Student) context.getBean("student");
    TargetSource targetSource = (TargetSource)
      student
        .getClass()
        .getMethod("getTargetSource", null)
        .invoke(student, null);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(targetSource.getTarget()));
 }
}
```

This works for me with your code, but I did not use Lombok (which you did not mention at all, I just found out when trying to compile your code!) in the mix but manually created constructors, getters and setters just to get up and running.

Besides, you do not need the `ExclusionStrategy` anymore.

**Console log:**

```
{
  "age": 11,
  "name": "Zara"
}
```

BTW, Lombok is known to cause trouble in connection with AspectJ because of class naming conflicts, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157868/1082681). This might also affect Spring AOP.

I think that you use an unhealthy (because incompatible) mix of technologies here, if you find a solution and do not want to end up writing custom type adapters for each bean class it will be quite hacky. If you remove Lombok, at least you can switch from Spring AOP to [AspectJ with LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) in order to get rid of the proxy problem. AspectJ does not use proxies, so GSON might work better with it.

---

**Update 2:**

My first update was just a quick hack during a tea break. Not being a Spring user, I had too look up the API doc first in order to find interface [`Advised`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/Advised.html). It contains method `getTargetSource()`, i.e.:

- We can cast our Spring bean (AOP proxy) to `Advised` and thus avoid ugly reflection.
- Going one step further, we can dynamically determine if a given object is an (advised) proxy or not, i.e. if you change or deactivate your aspect, the same code will still work.

```java
package com.tutorial;

import org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("aop.xml")) {
      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
      Student student = (Student) context.getBean("student");
      System.out.println(gson.toJson(unProxy(student)));
    }
 }

  public static Object unProxy(Object object) throws Exception {
    return object instanceof Advised
      ? ((Advised) object).getTargetSource().getTarget()
      : object;
  }
}
```

---

**Update 3:** I was curious and also installed Lombok for my IDE. Actually the sample from above does work in connection with Gson and my little `unProxy(Object)` method. So you are good to go. `:-)`

Comment: Yes you are right. It's not tricky to hack for this case (just call  `getTargetSource` if obj is a proxy).

Comment: After work I looked into it again and have just added an improved example without reflection in my second update. Feel free to take a look.

Comment: Update 3: added info about Lombok. Enjoy!

Comment: I really like lombok and use it anywhere possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can use @Expose annotation to ignore aop fields.
eg:

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
String json = gson.toJson(new Book());

```
public class book {

    @Expose
    public String name;

    @Expose
    public int some;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement `ExclusionStrategy` like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExcludeListedClasses implements ExclusionStrategy {
    @NonNull
    private Set<Class<?>> classesToExclude;
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return classesToExclude.contains(clazz);
    }
}
```

Use like:

```
ExclusionStrategy es = new ExcludeListedClasses( new HashSet<Class<?>>() {{
                add(Logging.class);
    }} );

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
                .addSerializationExclusionStrategy(es).create();
```

There might appear other unserializable classes also, added by aspects or so. Just add those also to the set provided when constructing `ExcludeListedClasses`.

The difference to Arun's answer is that this way you do not need to add `@Expose` annotation to each class's each field where would possible be unserializable fields.

You can also use method `shouldSkipField(..)` in a similar way if you want to skip serialization by field name, for example.