# How to exclude classes from triggering Aspect method call

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I have a method in an `@Aspect` service method called `logChangesAndAnnounceNewContributions` that fires whenever somewhere in the webapp the save method of Spring-data's `JpaRepository` is called. I don't want the logChanges method to be called when the save method is used within the Aspect class itself, so i used this in the pointcut definition  `!within(Services.SystemListenerService)`. But its not having any effect! The save method is still being called despite using this condition in the definition. The full definition looks like this:

```
@AfterReturning("execution(* org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.save(..))" +
           "&& !within(Services.SystemListenerService) && args(entity)")
    private void logChangesAndAnnounceNewContributions(Object entity){
```

What am i missing here?

EDIT: I tried changing !within content to `!within(@org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect *)` but that doesn't work either..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Services.SystemListenerService` is the fully qualified name of your aspect (class name `SystemListenerService`, package name `Services` with strange upper-case first letter), `within()` does not work because at the time of `execution(* org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository.save(..))` we are not `within(Services.SystemListenerService)` anyway but rather `within(org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository)`. So there is the logical error in your pointcut.

There are ways to solve this in AspectJ, such as

- `call(A) && !adviceexecution()`,
- `execution(A) && !cflow(execution(B))`,

but both pointcut types are [unsupported in Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). So you

- either need to [activate full AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) in Spring
- or abuse some Spring methods in order to [get the real object underneath the proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48980140/1082681) via `((Advised) myProxy).getTargetSource().getTarget()` and call the method directly on that object from your aspect
- or obtain a stack trace from a newly created exception or from the current thread and inspect it manually - very ugly.

Sorry, but Spring AOP is just "AOP lite", I think you should go for AspectJ. The second option is also a bit hacky but will probably work.

Comment: great answer. In the end i just made a work-around by using `within` to indicate in which class the aspect method should be called instead of in which class the aspect shouldn't be called.